Does a proper documentation of ALSA configuration exist?
I'm trying to set up a somewhat non-standard sound configuration on my system hence searching for the alsa documentation for that.
What I could find on the official alsa site:

https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Asoundrc - is not a documentation - it's a tutorial (which neither has nor promises to be comprehensive)

There's also a Configuration section in API documentation (in the bottom of the page): https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/index.html and

asoundrc.txt file in alsa-lib source code https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alsa-project/alsa-lib/b154d9145f0e17b9650e4584ddfdf14580b4e0d7/doc/asoundrc.txt
They both have some useful information on syntax, but look not structured and not exhaustive.


Dealing with all this feels more like reverse-engineering than studying a documentation.
I'm looking for a text along the lines of:

asoundrc configuration file is a text file, a sequence of definitions separated by... , where each definition can be either... or ... , the syntax of definition: opening bracket, then lines of name-value pairs.... nesting... list of (all!) possible definitions: PCM definition is for... parameters: ... , some other definition is for ... parameters... etc. etc.

Since i have, due to my needs, to study ALSA close, i thought - if there's really no documentation targeted for users, that i'd find satisfactory - I should contribute and write one once I learn it well enough. So am double-checking here for the case I'm missing some already existing, better documentation elsewhere


Isn't that the 1st section of asoundrc.txt? The part above # *****? 2) unit tests


that's just basic syntax. but after *** goes the list of things supposedly writable in this syntax, and there nearly every single line raises questions: what's a server in this context? what is pcm_type? scope? scope_type? what/how/why/what for is redirect? slave? literally every line is more like that auto-generated from code documentation template, than actual documentation

p.s. right now alsa-project.org is down and i cannot find a mirror, so cannot check how possible to find the answers to these questions from the wiki, but i don't think there's any indexed document there on this - i would probably notice it

oh, wait, i forgot about the wayback machine... i'll check wiki for that now

Some documentation is also in https://docs.kernel.org/sound/kernel-api/index.html : note: I think some part of configuration is just dynamic to push data to kernel (and then each driver define the parameters), so user space may not know all configuration options (nor the link I gave, which it is generic, and each driver decide)

@Gaicomo this seems to be specifically for driver creators, although it might help with understanding some bits later - thank you

@darkdiatel: yes, but as i said, I think much ALSA configuration is dynamic, and so the real answer would be "nobody but the kernel driver writer knows".

sounds fun)) okay, thank you. my goal for now then is to figure out the part that a user CAN possibly know/configure and compile what I'd personally like more as a documentation - for the users. since whenever i had to deal with alsa configuration, it always seemed a bit like a voodoo, including all the successful configuration users shared online
i'm reading https://www.volkerschatz.com/noise/alsa.html at the moment
